# PyDev Auto-Complete Doesn't Work

Tags: python, django, pydev

Today I reinstalled my OS (Ubuntu 11.10) and installed Django and PyDev.
I ran one of my programs that import Django framework. It works, but PyDev doesn't detect my project, Django, Simple Django Captcha and most Python libraries.
What can I do to fix this problem?

Actually, I must say I configured my PYTHONPATH in PyDev, too.

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't detect`? Also, how can your question title be related to that problem?

Comment: When I Press ctrl + space, Don't Any Suggestion From My Apps And Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New versions of PyDev should have Django integration. Try looking [here](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html).

Also, it might help defining those libraries as [Forced Builtins](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#id1). I had to use it to get PyQt auto-complete working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the some problem when I upgraded my Ubuntu, it was fixed when i installed the aptana studio package fully.

Comment: I Install Aptana Studio Too. But It's Not Working Yet!

Comment: I had also updated Eclipse, it s the Indigo version. i have no problem now.